# ExampleMatcher query with accessor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a case similar to this one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")

final public class Employee implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long empNo;

private java.sql.Date birthDate;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "gender", nullable = true)
private String genderId;

private java.sql.Date hireDate;

@ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "dept_emp",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_no"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dept_no"))
private List<Department> departments;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "gender", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private GenderLOV genderLov;
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gender_lov")
final public class GenderLOV implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "gender_id")
String genderId;

@Column(name = "gender")
String gender;

public String getGenderId() {
    return genderId;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGenderId(String genderId) {
    this.genderId = genderId;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public GenderLOV(String genderId, String gender) {
    this.genderId = genderId;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public GenderLOV() {
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return gender;
}
}
```

I'm trying to use ExampleMatcher the following way

```
 ExampleMatcher matcher = matching().withIgnoreNullValues().withIgnoreCase("firstName", "lastName").withIgnorePaths("empNo", "genderLov.gender", "genderLov")
            .withMatcher("firstName", contains())
            .withMatcher("lastName", contains())
            .withMatcher("genderLov.genderId", exact());
    Example<Employee> employeeExample = Example.of(employee, matcher);

    Page<Employee> employeesPage = repository.findAll(employeeExample, new OffsetBasedPageRequest(offset, limit));
```

It Works fine for Last and First names but when I try to filter by gender nothing happens.
My guess is that this is something to do with the @ManyToOne associacion
for the field genderId.
Is there any way of achieving this kind of filtration?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.matchers. check the limitations section

Comment: I've read this article about 5 times. There's no reference to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately looks like Example is not supported relations except @OneToOne.

From doc limitations: `Currently, only SingularAttribute properties can be used for property matching.`, and in our case it is not `SingularAttribute`, it is simply ignored.

For this you can have custom implementation of repository with needed Critearia building.